# How can i calculate the rotation the player need to make to get to the next waypoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public Transform target;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float slowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float reverseSlowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
    private int targetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private GameObject[] players;
    public Transform reverseTarget;
    private int reverseTargetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 reverseOriginalPosition;
    public bool random = false;
    public bool getNextRandom = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");
        players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        originalPosition = players[0].transform.localPosition;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (random == true)
        {
            RandomWayPointsAI();
        }
        else
        {
            WayPointsAI();
        }
    }

    private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
            targetsIndex = 0;
        target = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;

        if (MovePlayer())
            targetsIndex++;
    }

    private void ReverseWayPointsAI()
    {
        if (reverseTargetsIndex == 0)
            reverseTargetsIndex = waypoints.Length - 1;
        reverseTarget = waypoints[reverseTargetsIndex].transform;

        if (MovePlayer())
            reverseTargetsIndex--;
    }


    void RandomWayPointsAI()
    {
        if (random == true && getNextRandom)
        {
            int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
            target = waypoints[index].transform;
            getNextRandom = false;
        }
        getNextRandom = MovePlayer();
    }

    bool MovePlayer()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(players[0].transform.position, target.transform.position);
        players[0].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(players[0].transform.localRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - players[0].transform.localPosition), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        if (distance < 30)
        {
            players[0].transform.localPosition += players[0].transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            players[0].transform.localPosition += players[0].transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < target.transform.localScale.magnitude)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    void DrawLinesInScene()
    {
        // draw lines between each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);
        }

        // draw a line between the original transform start position 
        // and the current transform position //
        Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, players[0].transform.position, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawLine(reverseOriginalPosition, players[1].transform.position, Color.red);

        // draw a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
        // each time reached a waypoint.
        if (target != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, players[0].transform.position, Color.green);
        if (reverseTarget != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(reverseTarget.transform.position, players[1].transform.position, Color.green);
    }

    void AddColliderToWaypoints()
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in waypoints)
        {
            SphereCollider sc = go.AddComponent<SphereCollider>() as SphereCollider;
            sc.isTrigger = true;
        }
    }
}
```

There are two problems with the script.

If the Move Speed is set to 3 i need to set the Rotation Speed at least to the 10 if i will set the Rotation Speed to 3 or 4 or 5 the rotation will be too wide and it will take much time to the player to get back on track after rotating.

But if it's 10 it seems he is almost rotating on the place so it's not good either.

I want to be able to change the player rotation speed but also to keep him on the waypoints track at any time. I mean that each waypoint the player is reaching to that he will get to it's center. In this case cubes so not only to touch the waypoint but to get to it's center then moving to the next waypoint.

Another problem i see is with the RandomWayPointsAI()

When i change it to use the random method i'm not sure if it's just picking up random positions around the grid or if it's picking random blocks(Cubes).
But it's never getting to a cube it' getting close or between two or sometimes on a cube and same as before also on the random i want to make the random waypoints not just positions but blocks and to get to each random block center.

Center i mean like standing on it.

Comment: A picture of the situation may help.

Comment: @code11 It's hard to catch some screenshots at the exact points. So i recorded a very small video clip showing the problems. You can see it's not even getting to the last waypoint(block) in each line of the grid. It's rotating before the last one or before the last two. At time 1:05 in the video i change the rotation speed and at 1:30 i change it to random mode. https://youtu.be/-zeoumQrBQ8

Answer (score 1):

A glaring problem in the showcased code is the use of local positions and rotations. When moving and rotating characters and objects in the world you should use world space.

Localposition and localrotation are based on the position and rotation of the parent object. Using those to move your object across the world will cause weird problems.

I think the following answer has a pretty accurate explanation of that stuff https://teamtreehouse.com/community/global-space-vs-local-space